# How Can I Calculate No Of Days From Two Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Calculate no of days from two dates My date Format is `dd-mmm-yyyy` Like `"10-Nov-2020"`
Can any one help me on same?

```
<script>
        var deFromDate;
        var deToDate;
        var statarr;
        function deFromDateChanged(s, e) {
            deFromDate = (s.GetInputElement().value)
            //statarr = deFromDate.split('-');
        }
        function deToDateChanged(s, e) {
            deToDate = (s.GetInputElement().value)
            var Difference_In_Time = deToDate.getTime() - deFromDate.getTime();
            var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
            alert(Difference_In_Days);
        }

    </script>
```

I am getting Error on `getTime()` Is there any other Approach to do same

Comment: I would assume `value` is returning a string. You need to convert it to a Date object. Assuming it's in a valid format use `new Date(value)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard I have seen this answer but both scenarios is different from myone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) (though it is discouraged due to inconsistent implementation)

```js
function datediff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}

const deFromDate = Date.parse('10-Nov-2020');
const deToDate = Date.parse('15-Nov-2020');

console.log(datediff(deFromDate, deToDate));
```

Manual parsing

```js
var months = {
    'Jan' : 1,
    'Feb' : 2,
    'Mar' : 3,
    'Apr' : 4,
    'May' : 5,
    'Jun' : 6,
    'Jul' : 7,
    'Aug' : 8,
    'Sep' : 9,
    'Oct' : 10,
    'Nov' : 11,
    'Dec' : 12
}
function parseDate(str) {
    var [dd, mmm, yyyy] = str.split('-');
    return new Date(yyyy, months[mmm]-1, dd); // months are 0 indexed
}

function datediff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}

const deFromDate = parseDate('10-Nov-2020');
const deToDate = parseDate('15-Nov-2020');

console.log(datediff(deFromDate, deToDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Regex:

```
 <script>
        var deFromDate;
        var deToDate;
        var dt1;
        var dt2;
        function deFromDateChanged(s, e) {
            deFromDate = (s.GetInputElement().value)
            dt1 = new Date(deFromDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
        }
        function deToDateChanged(s, e) {
            deToDate = (s.GetInputElement().value)
            dt2 = new Date(deToDate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
            var result = ((dt2 - dt1) / 86400000);
            alert(result);
        }

    </script>
```